# XML to CSV in C# newbie

Tags: c#, xml, csv

Hello Guys i need help with this xml data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml-data xmlns="http://www.lucom.com/ffw/xml-data-1.0.xsd">
<form>catalog://Unternehmen/ust/ZM_Formular_online</form>
<instance>

<dataset id="tbl_ZM_tabelle">
  <datarow>
    <element id="knre1">AT</element>
    <element id="knre2">U18713701</element>
    <element id="umsatz_art">0</element>
    <element id="betrag">7605</element>
    <element id="zeile_m">1</element>
  </datarow>
```

I want to write a csv data by using the knre1,knre2 and "betrag" id's. Its always the same name.
It should be looking like this

AT;U18713701;7605

Iam a totally newbie in c# and i need the help.

Comment: Please type "c# convert xml to csv" into your search engine of choice and start reading through the numerous, well documented, articles and example code that completely answer your question.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: i can implement the csv file into my c# program
but i need to read the xml file and create a csv file

Answer (score 0):

This is something very basic:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

foreach (XElement datarow in xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("dataset/datarow"))
{
    string knre1 = datarow.Elements("element").Where(i => i.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("knre1")).First().Value;
    string knre2 = datarow.Elements("element").Where(i => i.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("knre2")).First().Value;
    string betrag = datarow.Elements("element").Where(i => i.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("betrag")).First().Value;

    csv.AppendLine(knre1 + "," + knre2 + "," + betrag);
}

File.WriteAllText("cvsFile.csv", csv.ToString());
```

Comment: its creating a file but it will not filling it with the xml element id's in the csv file

Comment: XElement datarow in xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("dataset/datarow") 
After this line i set a message box but its not getting there

Comment: @ofice so the xpath(instance/dataset/datarow) is incorrect ... it works for me with the example you used above. if you're using something else please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\edvazubi\\Desktop\\ZM05.2015.xml");
        StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (XElement datarow in xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("instance/dataset/datarow"))
        {


            string knre1 = datarow.Elements("element").Where(i => i.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("knre1")).First().Value;
            string knre2 = datarow.Elements("element").Where(i => i.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("knre2")).First().Value;
            string betrag = datarow.Elements("element").Where(i => i.Attribute("id").Value.Contains("betrag")).First().Value;



            csv.AppendLine(knre1 + "," + knre2 + "," + betrag + "L");
        }

        File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\edvazubi\\Desktop\\CSVFile.csv", csv.ToString());
```

this is my file now